# Btn not going to my flask endpoint when clicked

Tags: python, flask

I have a btn which allows a user to download a file.

```html
<a href="/download" target="_blank">
    <button class="...">Download Data</button>
</a>
```

This is my endpoint which allows user to download the file

```py
@app.route("/download")
def download_file():
    return send_file("./files/sellerjson_output.csv", as_attachment=True)
```

When I click the button, nothing really happens, (url doesn't change) it just hangs. However when I go to the route myself by typing it into the browser it works fine.

In the console I just get an extra POST request `127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2021 20:30:24] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -` but when I type `127.0.0.1/download` into the browser I get:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2021 20:31:10] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2021 20:31:12] "GET /download HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: You seem to confuse between `POST` and `GET`

Comment: The POST is correct I was POST data from a form to a db, before clicking the button. I was hopefully trying to explain that when I clicked the btn nothing happened until I manually went to the url

Comment: When you append '/download' to the URL manually, what happens?

Comment: the file downloads.

Comment: When you click the button does it download the file?

Comment: When I click the button the app just hangs. I go to check the url and it hasn’t been changed. Still the root url

Comment: From reading your code that is what I expected to happen. If the file doesn't download when you click the button, it's because your `href=/download` is wrong. What your `"/download`" route does is execute when you go that that URL, but it happens extremely fast and brings you back to the page you called from, is a way you could think of it. It is **not** supposed to change the URL.

Comment: My suggestion is use my solution and refresh your browser with `Shift + F5`.

Comment: Is your button embedded within a <form> block and is the form target properly set ? It should be `url_for('download')`

Comment: no it's just a <a> tag with a button tag. `<a href=""><button>click me</button></a>`

Comment: @JakeJackson that didn't work either. :(

Comment: Sorry to keep asking but it hasn't been made clear: when you **click the button** does it download the file?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the <button> and just keep a plain <a href> link ? In case you're using Bootstrap, links can be styled like buttons.

Comment: @JakeJackson no it doesn't do anything

Comment: the link wraps a button so that shouldn't be the issue...how do I get the namespace of the function ?

Comment: The code I gave you should call the function. If you are saying it doesn't work, something else in your code must be wrong. Also, again, **your function you are calling does not change your URL when you click the link since it doesn't render a new page**. It only "changes" when you physically type the URL and click enter. I can't help you any further, good luck.

Comment: When you are clicking on the button, I don't think the link is actually being triggered because of the way you are embedding HTML tags. Try a plain href link to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to be using `{{ url_for(#) }}` to call Flask routes inside your HTML.

```
<a href="{{ url_for('download_file') }}" target="_blank">
    <button class="...">Download Data</button>
</a>
```

Flask allows you to use templating, something that is helped by the use of Jinja.

Comment: This didn't work, it just hangs...after clicking the btn and checking the url it's still the home url. surely the url should link to the endpoint and not the function?

Comment: Well, either way, your function doesn't change URLs, so it is just meant to *hang*, as you say. It just calls the function and runs it.

Comment: This was the correct way of implementing it, after using `app.logger.debug(f"This endpoint is: {request.endpoint}")` to confirm the endpoint

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, upon looking at my HTML I had the button inside a form. DOH!!!

Moved the button outside of the form, and BOOM! click the button and file download complete!!!